# Replace the header's date in various .doc documents

Tags: vba, replace, header, find, format

I'm trying to replace the date in the header in various documents.
I don't care if the date it's already in the script or if the program require arguments.
The header date's format it's like this one: 22/02/2015 and I want to replace with the actual date with the same format.
This is the code that I have done:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceFirstStoryOfEachType()
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.MultiLine = True
  Dim rngStory As Range
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With rngStory.Find
      .Text = "([1-12]{1,3}/[1-09]{1,2}/[1-2014]{1,4})"
      .Replacement.Text = "<DATE>"
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
  Next rngStory
End Sub
```

I have seen a code to apply to the documents in a carpet but when I use it doesn't work:

```
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Nueva carpeta\*.doc")
```

EDIT: I don't know how to insert my last code in the other vba to open the files in the folder C:\Nueva carpeta. Did you say to create a .doc word in C:\Nueva carpeta and then create a module with the answer code right? But in this  new module I have to call or paste my code or what?

Comment: What does "actual date" with same format mean?  Isn't 22/02/2015 an actual date?  Or do you mean to replace it with current date

Comment: Replace it with current date

Comment: see if the answer provide resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a regexp as a search text, you have to test against the searched result to the regexp, then perform a replacement.  Also I have changed the regexp:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceFirstStoryOfEachType()
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.MultiLine = True
objRegEx.Pattern = "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"


Dim rngStory As Range
For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
If Not IsEmpty(rngStory) Then
With rngStory.Find
    If objRegEx.test(rngStory) = True Then

     .Text = CStr(rngStory)
     .Replacement.Text = Now()
     .Wrap = wdFindContinue
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
End With

End If
Next rngStory
End Sub
```

`Format(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")` can be use if you wish to change the format of the current date.  Also I am not sure if your last part of the question is having issue opening documents.

EDIT: [Open multiple documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240457/excel-vba-to-open-multiple-word-2010-documents-and-determine-if-checkboxes-are-c) might helps if you are looking to open multiple documents.

You can place below code to a template document and use it to open your other files:

```
Sub openf()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim fPath As String
Dim myFolder, myFile
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Variant

fPath = "C:\" 'change to your directory
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(fPath).Files
For Each myFile In myFolder
  If LCase(myFile) Like "*.docx" Then 'change to you file type
      Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(CStr(myFile))
      wdApp.Visible = True
      FindAndReplaceFirstStoryOfEachType
      wdDoc.Save
      wdDoc.Close
      Set wdDoc = Nothing
  End If
Next myFile

End Sub
```

If you still having issue on how it works, I will suggest you to read some basic vba coding tutorial:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx

Comment: Yes it works!  First of all thanks you for the interest. Now the problem is how I can apply this code to the header of various documents, I mean I have various documents in some carpet (In this case would be "C:\Nueva carpeta\*.doc") and I want to modify the date in his headers (With the code that you wrote). Thanks.

Comment: Hi again, I've been looking more information and I get this code to modify the header but with this code I can't move through the header, just modify the first header's cell: <ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader> Could I move through the header if I modify this code?

Comment: @Solaire are you saying you've multiple headers on the same documents, or you have mulitple documents?

Comment: Multiple documents, and I want to apply the last vba code in all those documents. The documents are in C:\Nueva carpeta

Comment: @Solaire I just added a link to the answer above.  You can have a template .docm file, insert the answer into a module, and use it to open multiple documents. (I will let you figure it out but please let me know if you're stuck)

Comment: I'm stuck xD, How I can assamble this code with the other? 
I tried several times but it gives me error

Comment: @Solaire could you show me where you stuck?  You can edit your question

Comment: @Solaire Please see the edit in answer.  Please accept answer so other helpers knows it has been resolved.

Comment: @Solaire Glad I could help.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code changes the header's date and works great:

```
Sub ModificarFechaCabecera()

If ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then
    ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Close
End If
If ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdNormalView Or ActiveWindow. _
    ActivePane.View.Type = wdOutlineView Then
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
End If
ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=14
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=3
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=4
Selection.TypeBackspace
Selection.TypeText Text:="/"
End Sub
```

Now, how I can execute this code in all .doc files at directory C:\Nueva carpeta ?
Greetings